# How to refer to a object that has just been hit by a ray cast?

Tags: unity, c#, raycasting

I would like to use `RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;`in order to freeze the rotation of an object that is picked up. The problem is I don't know how to refer (or call) the currently selected object. The script in it's currents state is below...

```
public class PhysGun : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject Player;

    void Start ()
    {
       Player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        Vector3 fwd = transform.forward; // Equivalent to the code you had.

        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 10f))
        {
            hit.transform.SetParent(Player.transform);
            Debug.Log("We hit: " + hit.transform.name);
            hit.transform. = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
        }

    }

}
```

So, how do I call (or refer to) the object that is hit by the ray cast exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rigidbody Contraints is a class to use for the rigidbody. In your case, instead of using `hit.transform. = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;`, I would replace that with `hit.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;`
I see that you have tried to set a *Rigidbody* class on a *Transform*. Rigidbody constraints take a `RigidbodyConstraints` class, as said in the docs [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-constraints.html). As I would guess, the source code might look similar to this:

```
public class Rigidbody {
    ...
    [SerializeField]
    public RigidbodyConstraints constraints;
    ...
}
```

The docs for the `RigidbodyConstraints` class is [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyConstraints.html).

Comment: The [RaycastHit class](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html) doesn't have a GetComponent method. I think you mean to say `hit.rigidbody`?

Comment: @DMGregory Is correct. Just add that and it works great. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @DMGregory In unity 5, `GameObject.rigidbody` is apperently deprecated, so, in this case, I used the `GameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>()` method.

Comment: My point is that `hit` as defined in the asker's code is *not* a GameObject. It is a RaycastHit, which does not have the GetComponent method. It does have a rigidbody property though (yes, including in Unity 5)

Comment: @DMGregory Ah. Thanks for correcting me. I will keep this in mind for the future.